# try to build objectbox on win10/64bit failed

Tags: windows, cmake

I am trying to build objectbox on Win10/64bit with `CMakeLists.txt` file and "mingw" --> at-end build from codeblocks.

BUILD LOG:

```
-------------- Build: all in objectbox-sync (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking if target is up-to-date: mingw32-make.exe -q -f Makefile
all Running command:
C:/mingw_gcc920_boost1710/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
"C:/objectbox-c-main/bin/Makefile"  VERBOSE=1 all "C:\Program
Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -SC:\objectbox-c-main
-BC:\objectbox-c-main\bin --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0 "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"
-E cmake_progress_start C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\CMakeFiles C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/mingw_gcc920_boost1710/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f
CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
'C:/objectbox-c-main/bin'
C:/mingw_gcc920_boost1710/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f
src-test\CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\build.make
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/depend mingw32-make.exe[2]:
Entering directory 'C:/objectbox-c-main/bin' "C:\Program
Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles"
C:\objectbox-c-main C:\objectbox-c-main\src-test
C:\objectbox-c-main\bin C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test
C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test\CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\DependInfo.cmake
--color= mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/objectbox-c-main/bin'
C:/mingw_gcc920_boost1710/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe  -f
src-test\CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\build.make
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/build mingw32-make.exe[2]:
Entering directory 'C:/objectbox-c-main/bin' [  3%] Building C
object
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/plain-c-test-main.c.obj cd
/d C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test &&
C:\mingw_gcc920_boost1710\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
@CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/includes_C.rsp -std=gnu99 -MD -MT
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/plain-c-test-main.c.obj -MF
CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\plain-c-test-main.c.obj.d -o
CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\plain-c-test-main.c.obj -c
C:\objectbox-c-main\src-test\plain-c-test-main.c [  7%] Building C
object src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/c_test_objects.c.obj
cd /d C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test &&
C:\mingw_gcc920_boost1710\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
@CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/includes_C.rsp -std=gnu99 -MD -MT
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/c_test_objects.c.obj -MF
CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\c_test_objects.c.obj.d -o
CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\c_test_objects.c.obj -c
C:\objectbox-c-main\src-test\c_test_objects.c [ 11%] Building C
object
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/__/external/flatcc-src/builder.c.obj
cd /d C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test &&
C:\mingw_gcc920_boost1710\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
@CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/includes_C.rsp -std=gnu99 -MD -MT
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/__/external/flatcc-src/builder.c.obj
-MF CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\__\external\flatcc-src\builder.c.obj.d
-o CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\__\external\flatcc-src\builder.c.obj
-c C:\objectbox-c-main\external\flatcc-src\builder.c [ 14%] Building C object
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/__/external/flatcc-src/emitter.c.obj
cd /d C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test &&
C:\mingw_gcc920_boost1710\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
@CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/includes_C.rsp -std=gnu99 -MD -MT
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/__/external/flatcc-src/emitter.c.obj
-MF CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\__\external\flatcc-src\emitter.c.obj.d
-o CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\__\external\flatcc-src\emitter.c.obj
-c C:\objectbox-c-main\external\flatcc-src\emitter.c [ 18%] Building C object
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/__/external/flatcc-src/refmap.c.obj
cd /d C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\src-test &&
C:\mingw_gcc920_boost1710\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
@CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/includes_C.rsp -std=gnu99 -MD -MT
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/__/external/flatcc-src/refmap.c.obj
-MF CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\__\external\flatcc-src\refmap.c.obj.d
-o CMakeFiles\objectbox-c-test.dir\__\external\flatcc-src\refmap.c.obj
-c C:\objectbox-c-main\external\flatcc-src\refmap.c mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target
'_deps/objectbox-download-src/lib/libobjectbox.dll.a', needed by
'src-test/objectbox-c-test.exe'.  Stop. mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving
directory 'C:/objectbox-c-main/bin' mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
[CMakeFiles\Makefile2:186:
src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/objectbox-c-main/bin'
mingw32-make.exe: *** [C:/objectbox-c-main/bin/Makefile:90: all]
Error 2 Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 49 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 49 second(s))  

BUILD MESSAGES:

||=== Build: all in objectbox-sync (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
[CMakeFiles\Makefile2|186|src-test/CMakeFiles/objectbox-c-test.dir/all]
Error 2|  [C:\objectbox-c-main\bin\Makefile|90|all] Error 2| ||===
Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 49 second(s))
===|
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, at the moment only the Visual Studio compilers are officially supported for ObjectBox on Windows. Please try it and come back if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).